# Changing the color of a BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Hi all I am calculating a fractal and drawing a bufferedImage based on the number of completedIterations. For the sake of simplicity lets I am coloring the bufferdImage using the completedIterations in this way:

```
g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor((float) (colorValue - completedIterations), 1F, 1F));
```

Where colourValue is constant while the image is being generated, lets say in this case it's 0.2.

I have a slider on a JPanel, which when used, changes the colorValue, in the range of 0 to 1.
When the colorValue is changed I want to update the BufferedImage in real time, but I don't want to recalculate all the image points as this causes a massive overhead - I just want to recolor the BufferedImage based on the new colorValue.

Can this be done, and if so how would I go about implementing it?

Kind regards

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set individual pixels using `setRGB()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7298492/230513); or adjust multiple pixels using `RescaleOp`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864503/230513).