# java NullPointerException when trying to draw

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw a picture based on a random array of numbers. So far I've had partial success, as the background color (white) does come up.

However, the picture does not draw. Instead all I see is the white background and this error:

```
PixelAvatarGen
XphnX
Black and white or 8-bit color?
0 = B&W, 1 = 8bit
1
Print name to make into avatar.
2
5:2:7:0:3:6:7:0:6:7:7:3:1:4:0:6:5:1:7:4:0:0:5:6:6:3:0:2:3:7:2:4:7:5:4:2:3:6:0:1:4:1:6:4:1:1:1:5:7:5:1:5:4:0:4:5:1:5:6:0:5:4:6:0:0:6:0:0:0:6:7:5:2:6:4:0:1:1:1:7:0:2:1:4:0:2:3:3:3:3:2:6:6:2:6:4:2:7:5:4:7:3:3:3:1:5:1:6:1:3:4:6:0:1:1:2:5:7:4:1:0:2:4:4:4:6:3:7:7:1:0:6:3:6:3:7:6:5:2:5:5:3:5:3:5:4:4:7:0:5:7:4:2:4:5:7:1:0:3:2:7:7:2:3:5:5:2:7:5:6:6:7:4:3:0:7:4:7:1:0:0:7:4:4:3:7:6:0:4:2:7:6:7:3:2:4:2:7:3:0:5:6:6:7:7:2:2:0:2:5:7:6:5:1:0:6:1:5:2:0:7:0:7:0:4:1:0:3:4:3:7:7:4:4:2:7:0:7:4:7:1:6:1:4:4:2:4:7:3:0:4:4:6:6:3:5:
Drawing11
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Drawing11
java.lang.NullPointerException
at xphnx.pixelgen.Screen.paintComponent(Screen.java:25)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at xphnx.pixelgen.Screen.paintComponent(Screen.java:25)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the complete output of the program. The "1" after 0 = B&W and "2" after "Print name to..." are user input.

Here is the Screen.java:

```
public class Screen extends JPanel {

  String[] pixels;
  Color[] proxlol;

  public Screen(String[] in1, Color[] in2) {
    in1 = pixels;
    in2 = proxlol;
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    int row = 1, column = 1, row10, column10;
    for(int i = 0; i != 256; i++) {
      System.out.println("Drawing" + row + column);
      g.setColor(proxlol[i]);
      if(i == 17 || 
          i == 33 || 
          i == 49 || 
          i == 65 || 
          i == 81 ||
          i == 97 ||
          i == 113 ||
          i == 129 ||
          i == 145 ||
          i == 161 ||
          i == 177 ||
          i == 193 ||
          i == 209 ||
          i == 225 ||
          i == 241
          ){
        row++;
        column = 1;
      }
      row10 = row*10;
      column10 = column*10;
      g.fillRect(row10, column10, 10, 10);
      System.out.println("Done drawing" + row + column);
      column++;     
    }
  }
}
```

In case needed, [Main.java](http://pastebin.com/WkKea2q2) and [Arranger.java](http://pastebin.com/Eh29zgjm) are on pastebin.

I've got little experience with Swing before. What's going on?

Comment: On a side note, next time please include ***relevant*** portions of your code directly into the question. Your exception stacktrace pointed you in the right direction for where the problem was actually occurring.

Comment: What is the fish it out there?

Comment: See also [`PiRaster`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7298492/230513).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never assign a value to your class variable `proxlol`.

```
public class Screen extends JPanel {
    String[] pixels;
    Color[] proxlol;

    public Screen(String[] in1, Color[] in2) {
        in1 = pixels;
        in2 = proxlol;
    }
}
```

You assign (to no effect) the uninitialized class variable to the input parameter `in2`. So, in your paint method when you reference the array of Colors you get an NPE.

Comment: Basically, I had the variables backwards. Thanks.